# Upgrading Facebook SDK (iOS) loses logged-in status

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-ios-sdk

[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] returns nil as our app initializes, but ONLY immediately following an upgrade of the Facebook SDK.

(This is not the same issue others have reported about losing Facebook log-in between instances.)

Specifically, this problem happens when upgrading (or downgrading) FBSDKCoreKit version 4.20.1 and below to any other version. Version 4.21 and higher do not exhibit this behavior when upgrading to higher versions.

Facebook appears to store log-in tokens in the app's keychain. The key FBSDKAccessTokenInformationKey does persist between upgrades, though it seems to be ignored after upgrading. Similarly, FBSDKAccessTokenDidChangeNotification does not fire after upgrading (until you log-in anew), whereas normally it will fire at every new instance.

Regardless of FBSDK version, log-in status does persist between instances so long as you've logged in and not upgraded the SDK. This inclines me to believe we have it all wired up correctly.

Since we appear to have what should be a valid access token and the Facebook SDK is ignoring it, is there a way to force a log-in with the existing token in the keychain? Or is there something else I've missed?

Comment: I'm having the same issue when updating our app from the Facebook SDK v4.18.0 to v4.24.0. Did you find any solution or have any more feedback regarding this?

Comment: We rolled back to the old version and shipped. Zero response from Facebook via their various support channels. If no solution is found before they cut off support, we'll have to design UX around forcing users to sign in again - which no user likes to be told.